# Segmented controll on Navigation bar with tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

At the moment I have app wich have Tab bar Controller with Navigation bar at the top.
My main goal is do something like this:
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/newtutorials/iphone/TabwithSegment/Final-image-for-Tab-with-Se.jpg
So it should look like image above, only segmented control will change table views.
Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 [segmentedControl setFrame:[self.navigationController.toolbar bounds]];

 [self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

Comment: +1 I needed to have it in UINavigationBar and that worked the same way for me. Thanks.